# error faced while working on jsp and mysql

Tags: jsp, jstl, scriptlet

while creating a login jsp page i m getting this error when the username and password is entered and clicked submitted...

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /loginbean.jsp (line: 9, column: 57) Attribute value request.getParameter("userName") is quoted with " which must be escaped when used within the value
org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:42)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:408)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:89)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseAttributeValue(Parser.java:280)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseAttribute(Parser.java:229)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseAttributes(Parser.java:162)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseAttributes(Parser.java:153)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseSetProperty(Parser.java:913)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseStandardAction(Parser.java:1134)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElements(Parser.java:1451)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseBody(Parser.java:1664)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseOptionalBody(Parser.java:1002)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseUseBean(Parser.java:958)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseStandardAction(Parser.java:1136)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElements(Parser.java:1451)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:138)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:242)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parse(ParserController.java:102)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:198)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:373)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:353)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:340)
org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:646)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

**Update 1**

JSP Code used is

`<jsp:useBean id="db" scope="request" class="logbean.LoginBean" >`

`<jsp:setProperty name="db" property="userName" value="%=request.getParameter("userName")%>"/>`

`<jsp:setProperty name="db" property="password" value="%=request.getParameter("password")%>"/>`

`</jsp:useBean>`

Comment: your jsp code please.... especially `loginbean.jsp (line: 9, column: 57)`

Comment: <jsp:useBean id="db" scope="request" class="logbean.LoginBean" >

<jsp:setProperty name="db" property="userName" value="<%=request.getParameter("userName")%>"/>
<jsp:setProperty name="db" property="password" value="<%=request.getParameter("password")%>"/>

  </jsp:useBean>

Comment: always edit in question as in question you can have it formatted... I will updated it...

Comment: your `LoginBean` code please...

Comment: package WEB-INF.classes;
public class LoginBean {
         
        String userName="";
     String password="";

        public String getUserName() {
            return userName;
        }
        public void setUserName(String userName) {
            this.userName = userName;
        }
    
        public String getPassword() {
            return password;
        }
        public void setPassword(String password) {
            this.password = password;
        }
    }

Comment: yeah thanks for updating .. i am new here so lil confusing...

Comment: check this... http://www.roseindia.net/jsp/jsp-bean-setproperty.shtml, this might help you

Comment: yeah i saw that ... wer i m going wrong i am not able to catch it

Comment: i m not able to figure it out ... feel like my code is correct...

Comment: search for `org.apache.jasper.JasperException:` on google... **HE** will help you  for sure... Good Luck!!!

Comment: can u pleas give some idea to run this... http://www.roseindia.net/jsp/loginbean.shtml

Comment: create the files that are provided and run `login.jsp`... check for `Brief description of the flow of application :`

Comment: i downloaded the whole code and made to run on apache it shows the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a brace in your scriptlet tags:

```
<jsp:setProperty name="db" property="userName" value="%=request.getParameter("userName")%>"/>
<jsp:setProperty name="db" property="password" value="%=request.getParameter("password")%>"/>
```

Should be:

```
<jsp:setProperty name="db" property="userName" value="<%=request.getParameter("userName")%>"/>
<jsp:setProperty name="db" property="password" value="<%=request.getParameter("password")%>"/>
```

However, I would recommend against using scriptlets in general. You can bypass the use of setting properties like this, and can access the objects by using the implicit `param` object with JSTL. This of course depends on what the rest of your JSP is doing, but it's considered best practice.

For example:

```
User name is: <c:out value="${param.userName}" />
```

Comment: actually i followed this article http://www.roseindia.net/jsp/loginbean.shtml  and found that error i directly downloaded the code and used it placing in my webserver same problem.... i m using apache 7 and jdk1.7

Comment: @S.A.Rahman: Roseindia.net is the *worst* source when it comes to "best practices" shown in code snippets. Put that site in your blacklist and just read official Oracle tutorials and/or real books.